# Width is going crazy at tailwind

Tags: css, width, tailwind-css

I have just discovered tailwind and want to change a simple div size. This happens .... that am i doing wrong here ?

How can it be explained that tailwind does not keep the width consistently?

```
<body>
   <div class="w-4 h-6  bg-red-500">1</div>
   <div class="w-6 h-6  bg-red-500">2</div>
   <div class="w-8 h-6  bg-red-500">3</div>
   <div class="w-10 h-6  bg-red-500">4</div>
   <div class="w-12 h-6  bg-red-500">5</div>
   <div class="w-14 h-6  bg-red-500">6</div>
   <div class="w-16 h-6  bg-red-500">7</div>
   <div class="w-18 h-6  bg-red-500">8</div>
   <div class="w-20 h-6  bg-red-500">9</div>
   <div class="w-22 h-6  bg-red-500">11</div>
   <div class="w-24 h-6  bg-red-500">12</div>
   <div class="w-26 h-6  bg-red-500">13</div>
   <div class="w-28 h-6  bg-red-500">14</div>
   <div class="w-30 h-6  bg-red-500">15</div>
</body>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sU6nj.png)

Answer (score 1):

Check [width](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/width) utilities - `w-18`, `w-22`, `w-26` and `w-30` are not present there so Tailwind does know nothing about its properties (there are no any properties assigned to this class unless you [modified](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/width#customizing-your-theme) your config) - therefore width of the element is full width because div is a block element